# I want to use company quota instead of individual sales user quota in collaborative forecasting

Tags: forecast, forecasts-collaborative, quota

as per our company policies we don't have individual quotas. How I can show the whole company quotas in collaborative forecast.

I am using forecast and upload quota for sales users. we don't want quota/budget for every sales users. We have company budget so how can I show company quota in forecasting.

[image]

[image]

I want to show quota amount only in red circle. so it will display whole month company quota and for sales users it shows as blank. so my question is how can I upload company quota.

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Comment: I edited the question please suggest any approach to achieve it @crmprogdev

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single Quota for the whole team, set that as the Quota for the Manager in the Forecasting Hierarchy. Example: Sales Manager Karen has 15 Sales Reps. Karen and the 15 Reps need to hit $1M in Sales this Quarter. Set the Quota for Karen at $1M. Do not load the Quotas for her Reps. The numbers will roll up via the Hierarchy and you will see the Quota and Quota Percentages when you view the Forecast as Karen.